# Gedcom Import Diagnostic Errors

Tags: gedcom, records, gramps

The standard behavior of Gramps [most current 5.x versions as well as 4.x and 3.x with which I have played in the past] is to conveniently create a Note record tied to an INDI or FAM or SOUR record when the gedcom importer detects a problem.  I understand and appreciate the implementation, but I am working with some rather large imports with rather large numbers of error reports [100K], almost all of which I can simply ignore.

As far as I know the only way to purge the db of those unwanted Notes [selecting them from the list of all Notes present upon completion of the import], results in a record-by-record delete which is probably done in the context of a transaction with locking and logging overhead. It is taking upwards of 45 minutes for the deletes to complete.

I had thought I had once stumbled upon a configuration option which allowed the user to by-pass the creation of Notes for problem imports, but I cannot find such an option now, so perhaps I am confused with some other gedcom-capable loader in some other implementation.

Can anyone tell me if there is a way to either bypass Note creation, or, if not, if there is some bulk delete utility tool somewhere which might accomplish the deletes in a matter of seconds?

Comment: You are probably better off asking this sort of question on a dedicated Gramps group. There are several listed at https://gramps-project.org/introduction-WP/contact/ there may also be a Facebook Group.

Comment: can you check if the notes are tagged? I know there is a tag in the csv import ("import 27-06-2019") so there could be one for gedcom. If that's the case it should be easy enough to select the notes you want to delete.

Comment: On this site, you can "Thank you" by upvoting the answers or comments by clicking the up arrow on the left :)